Sink CSV file with special structure with Azure data factory to PostgreSQL
I have on the Azure Storage Explorer a csv file from an API request. I want to build a pipeline on Azure Data Factory to sink this file as a table to PostgreSQL. My issue is that the format of the csv file cannot be easily converted.
The first row (cell) starts with the row numbers:
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24
Followed by the actual data on the next row:
"{'AccountID': '123456', 'CarrierID': '12-34-56', 'CarrierName': None, 'ControlID': None, 'ModifiedDate': '/Date(1401779596170-0400)/', 'OrderDate': '/Date(1401741929547-0400)/', 'OrderNumber': None, 'ShipToAddress': {'Address1': 'Road 4', 'Address2': None, 'Address3': None, 'Attention': ',', 'City': 'NY', 'ContactName': 'Johnson, John', 'Country': 'USA', 'EmailAddress': 'john.johnson@test.com', 'PhoneNumber': '12345678', 'PostalCode': 'test', 'State': 'NJ'}, 'Status': 'Cancelled', 'Column1': 'test-abcd', 'Column2': 'test-abcd', 'Column3': 'test-abcd', 'Column4': 'hello test', 'Column5': ['1234-abcd'], 'Column6': 'test-abcd', 'ColumnNumber': '54321'}",  
Separated by a comma, a new 'series' starts with exactly the same columns.
"{'AccountID': '123457', 'CarrierID': '12-34-57', 'CarrierName': None, 'ControlID': None, ..., 'ColumnNumber': '54320'}", 
And so on.
As we see the column ShipToAddress has multiple columns in it between the accolades {}. Furthermore there is a column, named Column5 with the data between brackets: ['1234-abcd'].
My question is how I can convert this in ADF to a simple table (with columns AccountId, CarrierId, CarrierName etc.) such that it can be sinked to PostgreSQL?
The ShipToAddress column can be left empty, but Address1, Address2 etc should all be separate columns. In Column5 the brackets should ideally be removed.

The data you provided is in incorrect Json format not in csv format, Could you please clarify about your data format?

@Bhavani Regardless what the data format is, this is how the data looks like and it is initially retrieved from the API as a csv file. I understand that it does not look like csv format and has more similarity with a json format, but still as you say incorrect json format.

If you able to modify the Json as  in this format,
then you will able to transform the data according to your requirement.

I do agree with @Bhavani that first you need to convert your data into a proper JSON file. Then, you can use ADF Dataflow to transform to your desired format and copy into your target table.
First create a delimited text dataset with your csv file and give below configurations.

Now, use a lookup activity on this dataset with below settings.

Then, use an array set variable activity with below expression.
@json(replace(replace(replace(replace(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),'"},{"Prop_0":"',','),'}"}]','}]'),'{"Prop_0":"',''),'None','null'))


The set variable activity will give the required JSON array.

Now, use a copy activity to copy this JSON array into a JSON file. You can follow the process in this SO answer to do that.
The JSON file will be created like below.

As the required JSON created, create a JSON dataset and use it as source in the dataflow and your Postgres table as sink in it to achieve your requirement.
UPDATE:
If every JSON string comes as "{}" in the lookup activity, then you can give the below configurations in the lookup dataset to avoid the extra double quotes "" in its output.


Thanks for your response. I get stuck at the Set variable activity. Apparently, I need to create a new variable. In your example this is named 'var1'. What should be the type? I can choose between: String, Boolean, Array, Integer.

Nevermind, it should be array since you mention above an 'array set variable activity'. However, I get an InvalidTemplate error in the Set variable activity and the message that 'The function 'json' parameter is not valid.'  What is going wrong?

Is the JSON same as above? or anything changed? Recheck the total expression and make sure you uncheck the first row option in the lookup activity.

Okay, I checked it with a file with the data as I stated above and that is working! Unfortunately, I see that my data structure in the original file is slightly different. Except the first series, every series afterwards is between "". So I have: {'AccountID': '123456', ..., 'ColumnNumber': '54321'}, "{'AccountID': '123457', ..., 'ColumnNumber': '54320'}", "{...}", etc. How can I handle this?

Give me some time, I will try and update the answer. Meanwhile please edit the question and add your original JSON structure with any dummy data.

I have reviewed my data once again and apparently when I open the file in Excel we have the first series not between "". But when I open the file in ADF as a dataset, we have the situation of: "{}", "{}", ... , "{}". I think this last case makes it easier to get a solution. I will edit the question.

Check the update section of my answer and let me know if you still face any issue.

I have tested it with a test file with two series (Quote and Escape characters settings as in your update) and three columns and get the error in the Set Variable activity: The function 'json' parameter is not valid. The provided value '["""{'AccountID': '123456', 'CarrierID': '12-34-56', 'ColumnNumber': '54321'}"",""{'AccountID': '123456', 'CarrierID': '12-34-56', 'ColumnNumber': '54321'}""""}]' cannot be parsed: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 1, position 1

Can you show your lookup activity output image and dataset configurations for better understanding? It's working fine for me.
